# Designing a peel-off style button

Tags: html, css

I have created a button with html/css that have a peel-off style.
My question is how do I set the border-radius of the triangles to match it with the button design? Any suggestion for improvements will be appreciated too. Thanks

[image]

```css
.offer-button-wrapper .coupon   {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.51px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C9E25;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.offer-button-wrapper .coupon:before   {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -185px;
  border-top: 20px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-left: 20px solid #2C9E25;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-button-wrapper">
   <a href="#" class="coupon">
      <div class="coupon-background">Reveal Coupon</div>
   </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS properties `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` can be used to give the desired border radius. But in order to correctly use these properties, border has to be applied on all four sides, instead of two. Below is the complete solution

```css
.offer-button-wrapper .coupon {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.51px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C9E25;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #2C9E25;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #f5fff4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.offer-button-wrapper .coupon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  border-top: 10px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #2C9E25;
  border-right: 10px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-left: 10px solid #2C9E25;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-button-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="coupon">
    <div class="coupon-background">Reveal Coupon</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code. i just changed the position of `:before` content. in this one you have to put the exact background color get the peel-off style.

```css
.offer-button-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: fit-content;
        height: fit-content;
        border: 2px solid #2C9E25;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    }
    .offer-button-wrapper .coupon {
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 17px;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 0.51px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #2C9E25;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    .offer-button-wrapper:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        right: -2px;
        border-top: 20px solid #ffffff;
        border-left: 20px solid #2C9E25;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="offer-button-wrapper">
   <a href="#" class="coupon">
      <div class="coupon-background">Reveal Coupon</div>
   </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**SVG: It's actually easier than CSS**

I assumed you're trying to radius the 45° corners as well, but I didn't realize until after this answer that you may not.

However, the best way to create custom shapes is to just draw them out using svg, in my opinion. You can write it yourself or use a vector program and go crazy, but simple things like this are easy enough to write like it's plain HTML:

[CodePen Working Sample](https://codepen.io/ryanjmcgowan/pen/NWxQWae)

```
  <svg>
    <path d="M 140 10
             H 270
             q 5 0, 10 5 
             L 285 20
             q 5 5, 5 10
             V 80
             q 0 10, -10 10
             H 20
             q -10 0, -10 -10
             V 20
             q 0 -10, 10 -10
             Z "
     style="fill:rgb(230,255,230);stroke:rgb(40,150,50)"/>
    <path d="M 270 10
             q 5 0, 10 5 
             L 285 20
             q 5 5, 5 10
             H 275
             q -5 0 -5 -5
             Z "
     style="fill:rgb(40,150,50);stroke:rgb(40,150,50)"/>
  </svg>
```

**Parameters:**

`path` parameters are:

`M` for move to a point.

`H` to move horizontally.

`V` vertically

`q` to create a three point curve with relative distances (capital `Q` is for absolute locations)

`Z` is to close the shape.

[You can check out the full svg path spec here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths), and as you can see there's not that much to paths.